# Cannot install rails on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I've been trying to install rails on my macbook, and have been having so much difficulty!
I installed RVM, and when I run "gem install rails," I get this message:

```
gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/stephanie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/stephanie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0 -I/Users/stephanie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/stephanie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR -I/Users/mpapis/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -fno-common -pipe -O3 -Wall -O0 -ggdb  -o generator.o -c generator.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o generator.bundle generator.o -L. -L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.rvm/usr/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1
```

I've tried googling solutions, but haven't found anything. Does anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552292/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: Maybe [this](http://rocksolidwebdesign.com/notes-and-fixes/ruby-xcode/) can help

Comment: yep I installed ruby. I'm looking at that site now, thank you!

Comment: hmmm downloaded the gcc installer, but still same error :(

Comment: The line `library not found for -lruby.1.9.1` does make me think there's a problem with your ruby install

Comment: reinstalled ruby and the rails install worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome :) I'll put that on an answer for future reference

Comment: Seems like rvm confuses about path. It uses both `/Users/stephanie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320` and `/Users/mpapis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320`. It should use rvm path under your folder `stephanie`.  AFAIK, rvm is should be in sandbox which is accessed by a single user only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting has an interesting line:

```
ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1
```

This makes me think there is a problem with your ruby install.

It seems there have been issues with Xcode and ruby installs on Mac computers (see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552292/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension), and an article on this over [here](http://rocksolidwebdesign.com/notes-and-fixes/ruby-xcode/)).

Reinstalling ruby should make thinks work.