# Unable to install posix-spawn

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems

I installed the Xcode 4.6.2 Command Line Tools via `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > Command Line Tools`, and its status is "Installed", yet after restarting my mac, running on Mac OS 10.8.3, I have no `/Developer` folder, and when I try to run `sudo gem install posix-spawn` I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing posix-spawn:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  -Wall   -c posix-spawn.c
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o posix_spawn_ext.bundle posix-spawn.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'posix-spawn.o'
make: *** [posix_spawn_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/ext/gem_make.out
```

[other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552292/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) suggest installing the Xcode Command Line tools, but I've already done that. `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` exists.

Comment: It seems that it has something to do with this line: `Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Developer'` if so, perhaps this previous question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961032/xcrun-error-could-not-stat-active-xcode-path-volumes-xcode-xcode45-dp1-app-c

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` and then `sudo gem install posix-spawn`.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Xcode worked for me. Run `xcode-select --install` and then install the gem with `gem install posix-spawn`.